# Java Generics, Inconvertible type, typecasting, heap d-ary

Tags: java, generics, heap, comparable, casting

This is my remove method for d-ary heaps. I'm getting a lot of 'inconvertible type' error when i compile. Also note that my program extends Comparable.

```
public class HeapImpl12<T extends Comparable<? super T>> implements Heap12<T>
```

I know my array is not type object but type T.

```
T[] _nodeArray = (T[]) new Comparable[DEFAULT_ARRAYSIZE];
```

Question: I understand everything should be type T, but when I was writing my code I got a lot of errors of "CAN'T CONVERT TYPE T TO TYPE INT", so i decided to typecast to make it same type (T) or (Integer). I realize now that doing this was wrong since I get "inconvertible type" error. Someone who has a high understanding on Java Generics please tell me techniques and tips to keep everything of type T.

```
public void remove(T o) {
    for(int i = 0; i < _nodeArray.length; i++){
        if(_nodeArray[i].equals(o)){
            _nodeArray[i] = _nodeArray[_numNodes - 1];
            if((Integer)_nodeArray[i] > parentIdx(i)){
                bubbleUp((Integer)_nodeArray[i]);
            }
            else{
                trickleDown((Integer)_nodeArray[i]);
            }

        }
        else{
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }


        _numNodes--;
    }

}
```

errors: happen when i typecast (Integer). I can post all of my code if you want me to but i think this is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really don't have to do much -- it's practically right as it is. Just take out the explicit casts and use `compareTo` in place on `>`:

```
public void remove(T o) {
    for(int i = 0; i < _nodeArray.length; i++){
        if(_nodeArray[i].equals(o)){
            _nodeArray[i] = _nodeArray[_numNodes - 1];
            if(_nodeArray[i].compareTo(parentIdx(i)) > 0){
                bubbleUp(_nodeArray[i]);
            }
            else{
                trickleDown(_nodeArray[i]);
            }

        }
        else{
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }


        _numNodes--;
    }
}
```

Comment: when i make methods like trickleDown and bubbleUp. does the parameters have to be of type T? like

Comment: public void trickleDown(T idx) or public void trickleDown(int idx){

Comment: @earbulan If you want to take an index, then no, it would be `int idx`. But if you want to take the object *at* that index, then yes `T obj`.

Comment: I get this Error: The method compareTo(capture#3-of ? super T) in the type Comparable<capture#3-of ? super T> is not applicable for the arguments (int).

Comment: The method bubbleUp(int) in the type HeapImpl12<T> is not applicable for the arguments (T)

Comment: @earbulan I think maybe you want to use `compareTo(_nodeArray[parentId(i)])` so you get the actual object stored at that position.